# How can I use a list of object in the model to automatically populate the options of a select in Thymeleaf view?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am working on a Spring MVC application that use **Thymeleaf** for the view.

I am absolutly new in Thymeleaf and I have the following problem.

At this stage of the work into a view I have a select which options values are hard coded into the code, something like this:

```
<select  id="selReg" class="form-control">
    <option value="" >--SELEZIONARE UN'AREA--</option>  
    <option value="areaUmanistica" >Area Umanistica</option>
    <option value="areaLinguistica" >Area Linguistica</option>
    <option value="areaScientifica" >Area Scientifica</option>
    <option value="areaPsicoMotoria" >Area Psico-Motoria</option>
</select>
```

Now, into my controller, I retrieve a list of **Tad1005Tipodisciplina** objects using a service and I put this list into the model.

```
List<Tad1005Tipodisciplina> listaTipoDisciplina = tipoDisiplinaService.getListaTipoDisciplina();

model.addAttribute("listaTipoDisciplina", listaTipoDisciplina);
```

This **Tad1005Tipodisciplina** class contain this field:

```
private String desTipDis;
```

that I want to use in my view to dinamically show the content of the previous select.

How can I use this list putted into the model to dinamically populate my select options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through your list using th:each in the select statement. This is where you define a variable that will represent each object in the list, which in turn you can use in each of the option tags like this:

```
<select id="selReg" class="form-control" th:each="object: ${listaTipoDisciplina}" th:field="*{listaTipoDisciplina}">
        <option th:value="${listObject.desTipDis}" th:text="${object.desTipDis}"></option>
    </select>
```

/Edit: A minute too late :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself, in this way:

```
<select  id="selReg" class="form-control">
    <option value="" >--SELEZIONARE UN'AREA--</option>  
    <option th:each="tipoDisciplina: ${listaTipoDisciplina}" 
            th:value="${tipoDisciplina.codTipDis}" 
            th:text="${tipoDisciplina.desTipDis}">
    </option>
</select>
```

Posted because maybe it could be util to someone in the future